# #2006 - MySQL server has gone away / Only in some databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, homebrew

I get this error (#2006 - MySQL server has gone away) trying to select some of my databases in phpmyadmin.

The error include this message:

```
SELECT `COLLATION_NAME` AS `Collation`, `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` AS `Charset`, `ID` AS `Id`, `IS_DEFAULT` AS `Default`, `IS_COMPILED` AS `Compiled`, `SORTLEN` AS `Sortlen` FROM `information_schema`.`COLLATIONS`
```

I have read and implemented many of the solutions proposed here, like including in my.cnf file, for example, the next:

```
[mysqld] 
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

And restarting mysql in each change (brew services restart mysql), but I still have the same error.

Like I said, I get this error only in some databases, I can work with the others without problem.

I have Homebrew environment on macOS Catalina, 10.05.3.
MySQL: stable 8.0.19 
phpmyadmin: stable 5.0.1 
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.2.6-41-ga80b89c

I apreciare your help.

Comment: increase the number massively slow databases need their time strat with 500k and increase the numbers till it gives an answer

Comment: Thanks nbk, I'll try as you recommend

Comment: see the result from **select @@max_allowed_packet;** and set it higher like **max_allowed_packet=500Mt;** or 1G in the my.cnf [mysqld] section and restart the server. If you have big resultsets (many rows or big Text fields the packet size is to low to transfer it